# What is the run time complexity of this program?

Tags: c++, runtime, time-complexity

The code is:

```
class RandomPancakeStack {
  vector<int> *del;
  double seen[256][256];
  public:
    double expectedDeliciousness(vector<int>&);
    double dfs(int size, int index);
};

double RandomPancakeStack::dfs(int pos,  int remain){
  if(pos  < 0) return 0.0;

  if(seen[pos][remain] != -1) { cout << "seen\n"; return seen[pos][remain];}
  double sum = 0.0;
  int i;
  for(i=0; i <=pos; i++){
    cout << " sum += "<< (*del)[i] << " + " << dfs(i-1, remain-1) << endl;
    sum += (*del)[i] + dfs(i-1, remain-1);
  }
  sum /= remain;
  cout << " sum /=remain " << sum << endl;
  seen[pos][remain] = sum;
  return sum;
}

double RandomPancakeStack::expectedDeliciousness(vector<int> &d){
  int N = d.size();
  int i,j,k;
  del = &d;

  for(i=0; i < 256; i++){
    for(j=0; j < 256; j++){
      seen[i][j] = -1;
    }
  }
  return dfs(N-1, N);
```

Is it O(N*N) ?

Comment: I guess there are better ways, but I would simply measure it. Measure the execution time for increasing values of N then you will see if it is O(N) or O(N*N)

Comment: unrelated to the question: If someone calls `dfs` before `expectedDeliciousness` you are screwed

Comment: @tobi303 would it be O(N^3)?

Comment: hum? I dont know. You are calling `dfs` recursively, wich makes it a bit complicated. It is much easier to know the complexity when you know the logic of the code. You know what you are doing, while I would first have to understand your code. I would still say: just measure it.